Shimano Hydraulic Disc Brake Recommendation For Trek Verve 3
I recently purchased a Trek Verve 3 and like many who bought it, the bike came with the substituted Ningbo Power hydraulic brakes instead of the spec Shimano MT200 brakes.
The existing brakes simply don't instill confidence, so I want to replace them with a set of Shimano hydraulics which I suspect might be more reliable and last longer. I'm 68 years old and use my bike for riding in my subdivision filled with cars, trucks, golf carts, joggers and walkers so I would be more comfortable with a reputable brand. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with bicycle hydraulic brakes and how they mount on different bikes, so I'm seeking advice from others here. I don't know the requirements for fitment other than I believe the caliper is post mount. But, I have no idea about the lever mounting on the handlebars.
The specs called for the bike coming with Shimano MT200 brakes, but I thought I could step up a bit to a higher grade Shimano set for not much more money. Can anyone tell me if either the Shimano MT401/410 or M6100 brakes would fit my Trek? And would one of those brakes be better suited for a Trek Verve 3 over the other?
Thanks for any guidance and knowledge shared.

Cannot offer recommendations - best to rephrase the question. What is it you are specifically wanting to improve? What fault or flaw are you experiencing, if any, or is it a perception Shimano will be more reliable?

Not really a full answer, but all brake levers for flat handlebars mount the same way. There’s a 22.2mm clamp that clamps onto the bars.

Product recommendations are off-topic here, but technical merits of the different ranges can be discussed.
The MT200 are a very good spec for a bike like the Verve, it's an upright comfort bike that won't reach very high speeds anyway. Most of the benefits you'll get from higher product ranges are mostly related to heat dissipation (that is only critical on long downhills) and adjustability rather than reliability. Performance as long as the brakes are "cold" is very similar and more limited by the tire than the brake itself.  For what it's worth, I noticed on my MT200 that fading only occurs after 300-400m of descent, but if you are not in a competitive environment, you can also just stop, enjoy the landscape while the brakes are cooling down and restart after. Reliability may be better on higher ranges, but my experience with the MT200 is really good (2 bikes, 3 years without requiring maintenance - except of course the replacement of pads - one e-bike used as commuter and one flat-bar gravel bike, ridden sportively).
On the differences: The MT201 is a 3-finger lever, while the MT401 is a 2-finger ones. After that, you'll get a different brake response curve (that impacts how the brake "feels"), toolless adjustment for the position of the lever (it can be adjusted on all Shimano levers, you need an hex key),... On the caliper side, it's mostly about heat dissipation (ceramic pistons, finned pads, rotors that are a sandwich of steel and aluminium, with or without cooling fins,...).
In short for a bike like the Verve, there's no downside of taking upper ranges, it might feel a bit better, but no practical difference.
EDIT: for the technical compatibility: if you have a full Shimano hydraulic setup, any flat handlebar lever will work, they are all mounted on the same way (caveats apply on higher-end MTBs, where the shifters are mounted on the brake lever, but that doesn't apply to a Verve or bikes of the same segments), and any post mount caliper will work (but no need to go a 4-piston caliper, a 2-piston caliper is more than adequate for the Verve).

Thank you very much for educating me. Since the 401 is a two finger lever, does Shimano make a 3 finger lever in that quality or better? My biggest issue is not understanding the fitment on the Trek so I know I can't just choose to use any Shimano set.

@Jimbo56: there's a list of levers on this page: https://bike.shimano.com/en-US/components/lifestyle/lifestyle-active/category/brake-lever.html (if your want Deore or above, ignore the levers in this list that are Acera or Alivio). You can also find the number of fingers in the "lever size" spec line. I edited the answer for compatibility.

Renaud, thank you for the edit and all the information you shared. I feel much better going forward.
